# Personalize ReactJS Pagination Style in Ant.Design - Is there any way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, antd

I'm developing a website based on ReactJS. Among different libraries, I've chosen Ant-Design (antd) due to its pretty elements. However, I do actually need to change some element styles. In Pagination component, I've chosen Simple mode which is shown in below image:

[image: Simple Pagination component]

The code for this component is:

```
<Pagination simple defaultCurrent={2} total={50} />
```

Is there any way to change the format of this component? Something like "2 from 5" instead of "2 / 5"? I know it has nothing to do with CSS!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to override the slash and replace it with an 'of' string using scss, code:

```
 .ant-pagination-simple-pager {
  .ant-pagination-slash {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  span::after {
    content: 'of';
    margin-left: 0;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

by updating the content to string `of` . I've attached a screenshot.

Comment: Seems like the screenshot has not been attached :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no built in way to change the `/` to something else, like `from`.

The slash itself is hardcoded in [this package here](https://github.com/react-component/pagination/blob/634cf2c24ea31eaead17f816887c2ebe8c0009b2/src/Pagination.jsx#L390). You could try opening an issue in that repo, or submitting a pull request where you add the option yourself.